# Unable to recognize host-gpu from guest

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, virtualbox, cuda

The Project:

Install CUDA 10.1 on vbox Ubuntu 18.10 via this tutorial https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

_

Host System Information:

Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362

GPU Nvidia GeForce GTX1080ti

Version of vbox: 6.0.10 r132072 (Qt5.6.2)

_

Guest Info:

```
(base) duluth@duluth-VirtualBox:~$ uname --kernel-name --kernel-release --machine
Linux 4.18.0-25-generic x86_64

(base) duluth@duluth-VirtualBox:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:    cosmic

(base) duluth@duluth-VirtualBox:~$ sudo update-pciids
Downloaded daily snapshot dated 2019-07-25 03:15:02
```

_

The Issue:

Unable to complete Step "2.1. Verify You Have a CUDA-Capable GPU"

```
(base) duluth@duluth-VirtualBox:~$  lspci | grep -i nvidia
(base) duluth@duluth-VirtualBox:~$
```

The output comes out blank, even after "sudo update-pciids"

Comment: You should make the Nvidia graphics card available in the VM: https://davidyat.es/2016/09/08/gpu-passthrough/